# follow erro message

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to install the library bs4 and i take the follow erro message

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/4d/16/0a14ca596f30316efd412a60bdfac02a7259bf8673d4d917dc60b9a21812/pip-22.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))).

I tried all the solution that had been given (like: `pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>`,)  but the problem continues. Also i    reinstall python 3.10.2 and now i have problem that pip didn't  recognized. I will appriciate yours answers.

Comment: This is all you have to do. `pip install beautifulsoup4`  https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/   have you tried this ?

Comment: Yes i tried this command and again i took the same error.

Comment: which operating system are you using ? do you have a firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this thread/solution: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10963 
If you are from Spain could be Vodafone's Secure Net.